# vscode not working with javascript since the latest update

Tags: visual-studio-code

so since the latest update, none of the javascript features is working.

- in all my js project. ( yes only js )
- no intellisense, no suggestion, not even talking on 'jump to declaration', basically a notepad with colours.

I have tried to delete extensions that may interfere. reinstall typescript  `npm i -g tsd`

also on vscode insider is the same. 
even when I run `code . --disable-extensions` nothing is working.

`$ code --status` ->

```
Version:          Code 1.41.0 (9579eda04fdb3a9bba2750f15193e5fafe16b959, 2019-12-11T17:58:38.338Z)
OS Version:       Darwin x64 17.7.0
CPUs:             Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz (8 x 2200)
Memory (System):  16.00GB (0.06GB free)
Load (avg):       3, 4, 4
VM:               0%
Screen Reader:    no
Process Argv:     /Users/pirate/websites/tipigo-spark
GPU Status:       2d_canvas:                     enabled
                  flash_3d:                      enabled
                  flash_stage3d:                 enabled
                  flash_stage3d_baseline:        enabled
                  gpu_compositing:               enabled
                  metal:                         disabled_off
                  multiple_raster_threads:       enabled_on
                  oop_rasterization:             disabled_off
                  protected_video_decode:        unavailable_off
                  rasterization:                 enabled
                  skia_renderer:                 disabled_off
                  surface_control:               disabled_off
                  surface_synchronization:       enabled_on
                  video_decode:                  enabled
                  viz_display_compositor:        enabled_on
                  viz_hit_test_surface_layer:    disabled_off
                  webgl:                         enabled
                  webgl2:                        enabled

CPU %   Mem MB     PID  Process
    3       82    8075  code main
    0       49    8076     gpu-process
    0      164    8079     window (add_to_dev.py — tipigo-spark)
    0      131    8082       extensionHost
    0       66    8103         electron_node server.js 
    0      328    8158         /Users/pirate/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.11.50794/languageServer.0.5.10/Microsoft.Python.LanguageServer
    0        0    8083       /bin/bash -l
    0       33    8084       watcherService
    0       33    8119       searchService
    0       66    8099     shared-process
    0        0    8376       /bin/ps -ax -o pid=,ppid=,pcpu=,pmem=,command=

Workspace Stats: 
|  Window (add_to_dev.py — tipigo-spark)
|    Folder (tipigo-spark): 37 files
|      File types: py(15) sh(4) pyc(2) cred(1) txt(1) text(1) zip(1)
|                  code-workspace(1) json(1)
|      Conf files: settings.json(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone in this problem, try upgrading your workspace to use typescript@next by installing [JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-next) extension